# Does the VisualTree exist before child page calls InitializeComponent?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to determine the best way to inject `UserControls` from a base page class in `UWP`. I have a base page class that wants to look for a `Grid` called ParentGrid in the `VisualTree`. ParentGrid is assumed to be defined on the child implementing page in order for the injection to take place.

But I'm uncertain, does the `VisualTree` exist with knowledge of the child pages elements during the base page's constructor? The child pages constructor has not been called, nor has it's `InitializeComponents` method.

When base page makes the call to `InitializeComponents` does that guarantee the xaml/parsing of the child pages elements, making them available in the `VisualTree`?

I'd like to avoid this scenario when injecting `UserControls` from a base page class.

```
 public ChildPageConstructor()
 {
     this.InitializeComponent();

     // Ideally would not do this every time, I want the base page to go find the parent grid and inject the UserControl if needed.
     base.BaseGrid = BaseGrid;
     base.ParentGrid = MainAreaGrid;
 }
```

Comment: When the base page calls InitializeComponent() it's child controls don't yet exist. Addtionally other controls could get added to the page from injectors and region managers. Searching the visual tree could be a performance hit, it's also an anti pattern because you have an implicit condition that you only have one grid called `ParentGrid`.

Comment: Yeah I agree searching the visual tree for a know element is inefficient. I guess I'm looking for a better way to give my base page class a handle to the `ParentGrid` in the child page. It's annoying if you can't inherit the xaml.

Answer (score 1):

Not so clear about your scenario.But if your child element hasn't been called anywhere. How can your parent know anything about your child page?

You can test it by calling [VisualTreeHelper Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper). But I think you will get exception there.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I figured so. But I wondered if there was also a better way to give my base page a handle to something in xaml on the child page in a more direct way. Instead of having to assign it in the child classes implementation. Xaml limitations perhaps.

Comment: @visc yep you cannot use this direct way. But if you have any logic and want to pass from main page to child page, you can think about [passing parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Frame_Navigate_Windows_UI_Xaml_Interop_TypeName_System_Object_). And then do something in your child page to show or hide your usercontrol.